# Delete everything after a number of characters in string in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, limit

The following is an example of 27 characters per line in Notepadd ++. I need to limit the characters per line to 14 characters.

> 111111111111111111111111111
>   222222222222222222222222222
>   333333333333333333333333333

I need it to look like the following:

> 11111111111111
>   22222222222222
>   33333333333333

How can I can limit the number of characters to 14 characters per line in Notepad++

Answer (score 6):

Find what: `^(.{1,14}).*`
Replace with: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

And also

Limit characters count in line and remove more that 14

Select Regular ext.Unselect matches new line

Find what: ^(.{1,14}).*
Replace with: \1

Save to macro.